# Connected Host / Hypervisor does not show up in network, but hosted VMs do

Tags: networking, connection, hypervisor

I have setup a Debian based hypervisor with a single Ethernet Device, such that `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like that:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto iface eth0.30
iface eth0.30 inet dhcp

auto iface eth0.7
iface eth0.gvlan inet manual
        vlan-raw-device eth0

auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
    bridge_ports eth0.7
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

So, a dynamic IP within vlan 30 for the Hypervisor and a bridge for all the VMs within vlan 7.

The problem is: I **can access** all services from the VMs and they show up on the router as well. **BUT** the hypervisor itself is gone. I can neither ping it nor does it show up on the router. Even with `sudo nmap -p-  10.10.10.0/24` I cannot see it popping up. How can that happen and is there anything I can do about it?